# Find all homomorphisms in these three examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How I should find all homomorphisms $$ f : G \rightarrow H $$ for examples:
$$ i) \ \ G = (Z, +), \ \ H = (Q, +) $$
$$ ii) \ \ G = (Z_{15}, +_{15}), \ \ H = (Z_4, +_4) $$
$$ iii) \ \ G = Z_2 \times \ Z_2, \ \ H = (Z_4, +_4) $$

I've never seen before this kind of a task, so I don't know even how it start.
Please help and thanks for yours answers. :-)

Comment: What do you know about homomorphisms - like the image of the identity element, the nature of the kernel, and the order of the image of an element which isn't in the kernel?

Comment: About homomorphisms I know few. Of course I heard about kernel, but  in practical I haven't experience. I'm trying learn abstract algebra on my own for five days :).

Comment: Take a cue from what Nicholas says in his answer about the images of generators defining the homomorphism. But learn about kernels - Normal Subgroups are kernels in group theory. They are fundamental if you are learning abstract algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $G$ is generated by $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$, then any homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ is completely determined by the choices of $f(g_1),\ldots,f(g_n)$. Do you see why?

Given this: what are the generators of the groups $G$ in (i), (ii), and (iii)?  What sort of elements must they be mapped to in order to satisfy the homomorphism properties?  How must, for instance, the orders of $g$ and $f(g)$ be related?

For instance, for (i): the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is generated by the single element $1$.  So, any homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is determined uniquely by $f(1)$. We can get homomorphism which maps all elements to 0 by choosing $f(1)=0$; what happens if you choose $f(1)=q$, where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $q\neq 0$?  These are all valid too, and map $\mathbb{Z}$ to $q\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For example (ii) answer is one homomorphism : $$ f(1) = 0 $$ ?

Comment: Right - the only homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ (the integers mod $15$) to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is the trivial homomorphism $g\mapsto 0$ for all $g\in \mathbb{Z}_{15}$. Why?  $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is generated by $1$, which has order $15$; so, $f(1)$ must have order which divides 15. Hence $f(1)$ must have order $1$, $3$, $5$, or $15$; but, only one of those is possible in $\mathbb{Z}_4$!

Comment: For example (i) answer is $$ f(t) = tf(1) $$ ? This is enough? Because I can't select the numbers of, I think so.

Comment: That's right, although I wouldn't quite state it that way; I would say that the homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ are the mappings $f_q(n)=nq$ for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ok, but I still understand how solve example number three, I know, that I should consider pairs of numbers. Can you help me again :) ?

Comment: Hint: The group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ consists of only four elements: $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$. Obviously you must map $(0,0)$ to $0$. How must $f(1,1)$ relate to $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$? Do $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ place any restrictions on each other?  Think about the fact that in the direct product, the coordinates are basically "independent".

Comment: Hmm, still it's seems weird for me, meanwhile I solved example: $$ G = (\mathbb{Z}_6, +_6), \ H = (\mathbb{Z}_4, +_4) $$ $$ \phi(m) = \phi(1 +_4 ... +_4) = \phi(1) +_4 ... +_4 \phi(1) = (m\phi(1))_4 $$
Know: $$ \phi(0) = 0 = (0\phi(1))_4 $$ so $$ \phi(m) = (m\phi(1))_4 \forall m \in Z_6 $$
$$ 0 = \phi(0) = \phi(1 +_4 ... +_4) = (\phi(1) +_4 ... +_4 \phi(1)) = (6\phi(1))_4 = (2\phi(1))_4 $$
So we can two diffrent homomorphism.
$$ Z_6 = \{0, 3\}, \{0, 2, 4\}, \{0, Z_6\} $$ $$ Z_4 = \{0, 2\}, \{0, Z_4\} $$ And know answer is: $$ f(1) = 0 \ \ f(1) = 2 \ \ or \ \ f(1) = 0 \ \ f(1) = 4 $$

Comment: My fault, $$ f(1) = 4 $$ it can't be :-), so only possible answer is $$ f(1) = 0 \ \ f(1) = 2 $$ :) ?

Comment: Can you check my solution? :)

Comment: Can you check my solution?